# cron задачи на 000webhost

Tags: php

Можете подсказать что не так? На хостинге имеется php файл который мне требуется запускать примерно каждые 10 минут, поставил cron-задачу на 000webhost, но скрипт не запускается. Можете подсказать в чём проблема? Или это проблема от самого хостинга?

[image: кортен0чка]

Comment: А как вы определили, что он не запускается? Может, он на самом деле запускается, просто завершает работу с ошибкой?

Comment: Я запускал его вручную, он отправлял запросы в телегу, через cron - нет.

Comment: Пишите в поддержку хостинга.

Comment: А что это за такая симпатичная "морочка" крона?